# Generating resource files

Tags: .net, localization, resx

I have a default resource file (resx) for my VB.NET control. I want to generate resource files  (resx) for Russian and some other languages based on this. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take a copy of your existing resx and rename it to `<Filename>.<Culture>.resx`. It'll automatically nest below the primary resource in the project tree within solution explorer:

[image: culture-specific resource files in Visual Studio solution explorer]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I can't do this in visual studio editor. Can you please elaborate more.

Comment: You can do it from Windows Explorer, then if you go back to Studio and hit "Show All Files" in Solution Explorer, you'll see the newly added file. Right-click and "include in project". Your application will automatically load the appropriate resx contents based on the active culture.

Comment: Thanks, So Just by renaming to  <Filename>.<Culture>.resx will convert the .resx file to corresponding culture automatically? Please confirm. How do I verify that my conversion is successful? Can I use  Win Resource Localization Editor to verify this?

Comment: That's right. I'm not familiar with the resource localisation editor, but you can just start your program in a different culture (programatically through `CurrentUICulture`, via web.config, or by changing the culture on your PC), then try to load data from your resource. You'll see that the data _will_ come from the appropriate file (make sure you have different content in the new resx). You can also confirm by looking in the bin folder after building - there will be extra satellite DLLs, one for each supported culture.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link on MSDN that may help you do it in VS: [Walkthrough: Localizating Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3)

I've used the the winres tool (Windows Localiaztion Editor) which comes with the windows sdk these days ... but its been a long time.